# how to use for loop after type casting a dictionary into a list?

Tags: python

I was type casting a dictionary into a list and then using for loop to print all the elements in that list. But it seems that the list only get the key elements of the dictionary. How to make the list so the it has the values of the key element too?

I've tried type casting the dictionary directly and then using for loop.

```
d1 = {"a":"s", "b":"t", "c":"u", "d":"v"}
d = list(d1)
for i, s in d:
    print(i, s)
```

This is the error that i got:

> File "C:/Users/Blank/PycharmProjects/proj1/Main.py", line 39, in
>   
>       for i, s in d: ValueError: not enough values to unpack (expected 2, got 1)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`list()` is not a typecast. It's an object constructor (for lists) that takes one iterable as argument. It will only contain the dict's keys, because that's what iterating over a dict does in Python. If you want to iterate over the (key, value) pairs in a dict use its `.items()` method. You can also save those to a list, like `list(d1.items())`.

Answer (score 2):

No need for a list, you can iterate over a dictionary.

dict.items() will will give you what you need.

> Return a new view of the dictionary’s items ((key, value) pairs). See the documentation of view objects.
>
> https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#dict.items

```
for key, value in d1.items():
    print(key, value)
```

Answer (score 0):

The error message is correct, when you converted the dictionary to a list, python kept the keys in the list and dropped the values. Try printing 'd' to see what I mean.

```
>>> d1 = {"a":"s", "b":"t", "c":"u", "d":"v"}
>>> d = list(d1)
>>> print(d)
['a', 'c', 'b', 'd']
```

so when you're looping on it, you only get one value, not two. You'll have to change your for loop to this.

```
for i in d:
    print(i)
```

Answer (score 0):

1). When you are converting a `d1` dictionary into `d` list, then in a list `d` you are only getting keys of dictionary `d1`.

```
d1 = {"a":"s", "b":"t", "c":"u", "d":"v"}
d = list(d1)
print(d)
```

OUTPUT --> `['a', 'c', 'b', 'd']`

2). You can use `d1.items()` method to get your desire result. I have modified your code to get keys and values of your dictionary `d1`.

```
d1 = {"a":"s", "b":"t", "c":"u", "d":"v"}
for key,value in d1.items():
    print(key, value)
```

Answer (score 0):

Rewrite your code:-

```
d1 = {"a":"s", "b":"t", "c":"u", "d":"v"}
d = d1.items()
for i, s in d:
    print(i, s)
```

**Output**

```
a s
b t
c u
d v
```